# Corrección de caracteres especiales en Select

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets

Tengo un select llamado desde un servicio web donde lo suelto en un Select, el tema es que tengo problemas con los caracteres especiales como la Ñ y °, quisiera saber como puedo solucionar aquello, ya que en la Base de datos esta ok. Comparto el codigo del Servlet

```
                for(int i=0;i<listar_eTitu.size();i++){
                    int Id_Area                  = listar_eTitu.get(i).getId_area();
                    int Id_EntidadTituladora     = listar_eTitu.get(i).getId_EntidadTituladora();
                    String Nombre                = listar_eTitu.get(i).getNombre();
                    String Observacion           = listar_eTitu.get(i).getObservacion();
                    select                      += "<option value='" + Id_EntidadTituladora + "' data-Area='"+Id_Area+"' data-obser='"+Observacion;
                    select                      += (id_select == listar_eTitu.get(i).getId_EntidadTituladora())?"' selected>" + Nombre + "</option>":"'>" + Nombre + "</option>";
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Presupuesto - Municipalidad de San Antonio</title>
<jsp:include page="include_css.jsp"></jsp:include>
<link href="assets/css/calendario_presupuesto.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
    .hidden-item
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .obligatorio-on-texto
    {
        font-size:12px;
        color: #bb2020;
    }
    .obligatorio-off-texto
    {
       margin-bottom:12px;
    }
    .tabla-personal-sol-eliminado
    {
        background-color:#FFC5C5;
    }
    .tabla-prod-center
    {
        font-size: 25px !important;
        text-align: center;
    }   
    .spinner {
      margin: 100px auto;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .cube1, .cube2 {
      background-color: #333;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;

      -webkit-animation: sk-cubemove 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation: sk-cubemove 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
    }

    .cube2 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
      animation-delay: -0.9s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes sk-cubemove {
      25% { -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5) }
      50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg) }
      75% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5) }
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) }
    }

    @keyframes sk-cubemove {
      25% { 
        transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5);
      } 50% { 
        transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-179deg);
      } 50.1% { 
        transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg);
      } 75% { 
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5);
      } 100% { 
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
      }
    }
</style>
```

```
    <!-- INCLUDE MENU PRINCIPAL -->
    <jsp:include page="menu_Left.jsp"></jsp:include>

    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

        <!-- INCLUDE MENU SUPERIOR -->
        <jsp:include page="menu_Up.jsp"></jsp:include>

        <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <h2>Cargar Ficha Presupuestaria</h2>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a href="solicitud_personal_new.jsp">Men&uacute; Principal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Presupuesto</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <strong>Solicitar Personal</strong> 
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <jsp:include page="include_js.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <jsp:include page="ficha_personal_new.jsp"></jsp:include>            
    </div>

    <!-- MENU FOOTER -->
    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>

    </div>

    <!-- MENU APOYO DERECHO -->
    <jsp:include page="menu_Right.jsp"></jsp:include>

    </div>
<!-- Modal Pre-Plan Compra -->
    <jsp:include page="pre_plan_compra.jsp"></jsp:include>
<!-- Mainly scripts -->

<script src="assets/js/functions_ctrl/load_menu_.js"></script>  

<!-- Calendario Presupuesto -->
<script src="assets/js/calendario_presupuesto.js"></script>  

<!-- Tipo Contrato -->
<script src="assets/js/functions_ctrl/tiposContrato.js"></script>
```

Comment: En el head de tú HTML utiliza la siguiente etiqueta. <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: ya lo tenia así... de igual manera ahora agregue el html

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre añado esta etiqueta en la parte superior de todas las páginas JSP

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Tienes mas información sobre el tema del encoding de caracteres en páginas JSP en este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723339/utf-8-encoding-in-jsp-page

Comment: sigue igual....

Answer (score 0):

Una pregunta, no veo donde imprimes el valor de tus variables en el jsp o como haces para agregar el código HTML de tu string en el jsp. Pueden ser dos casos o que el servicio que usas para extraer los datos de la base de datos sea quien te cambie los caracteres o el renderizado del jsp sea quien lo cambie, has debugueado el servlet y ver si te trae los datos de manera correcta?, recuerda que la manera en la que imprimes las variables puede ser diferente, por ejemplo:

```
<% Fragmentos de código %>
```

Se usa para agregar lógica en código Java

```
<%= "Hola Mundo" %>
```

Literalmente manda a llamar el método toString() e imprime la expresión.

Pueden existir varias maneras de llenar el select, puede ser desde un ciclo for usando las etiquetas  o un ciclo for dentro de las etiquetas <% %> JSTL.

Fuentes: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/jstl-foreach-tag-example-in-jsp-looping.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm